# FastAPI RedirectResponse gets {"message": "Forbidden"} when redirecting to a different route

Tags: docker, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, fastapi, serverless

Please bare with me for a question for which it's nearly impossible to create a reproducible example.

I have an API setup with FastAPI using Docker, Serverless and deployed on AWS API Gateway. All routes discussed are protected with an api-key that is passed into the header (`x-api-key`).

I'm trying to accomplish a simple redirect from one route to another using `fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse`. The redirect works perfectly fine locally (though, this is without api-key), and both routes work perfectly fine when deployed on AWS and connected to directly, but something is blocking the redirect from route one (`abc/item`) to route two (`xyz/item`) when I deploy to AWS. I'm not sure what could be the issue, because the logs in CloudWatch aren't giving me much to work with.

To illustrate my issue let's say we have route `abc/item` that looks like this:

```
@router.get("/abc/item")
async def get_item(item_id: int, request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    if False:
        redirect_url = f"/xyz/item?item_id={item_id}"
        logging.info(f"Redirecting to {redirect_url}")
        return RedirectResponse(redirect_url, headers=request.headers)
    else:
        execution = db.execute(text(items_query))
        return convert_to_json(execution)
```

So, we check if some value is True/False and if it's False we redirect from `abc/item` to `xyz/item` using `RedirectResponse()`. We pass the redirect_url, which is just the `xyz/item` route including query parameters and we pass `request.headers` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62282100/fastapi-redirectresponse-custom-headers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231936/python-fastapi-how-can-i-get-headers-or-a-specific-header-from-my-backend-api)), because I figured we need to pass along the `x-api-key` to the new route. In the second route we again try a query in a different table (`other_items`) and return some value.

I have also tried passing `status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER` and `status_code=status.HTTP_307_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT` to `RedirectResponse()` as suggested by some tangentially related questions I found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849929/fastapi-redirect-gives-method-not-allowed-error)  and the [FastAPI discussions](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1498), but that didn't help either.

```
@router.get("/xyz/item")
async def get_item(item_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    execution = db.execute(text(other_items_query))
    return convert_to_json(execution)
```

Like I said, when deployed I can successfully connect directly to both `abc/item` and get a return value if `True` and I can also connect to `xyz/item` directly and get a correct value from that, but when I pass a value to `abc/item` that is `False` (and thus it should redirect) I get `{"message": "Forbidden"}`.

In case it can be of any help, I try debugging this using a "curl" tool, and the headers I get returned give the following info:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 23
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2022 08:43:06 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
x-amz-apigw-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: XXXXX
X-Amz-Cf-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So, this is hinting at a CloudFront error. Unfortunately I don't see *anything* slightly hinting at this API when I look into my CloudFront dashboard on AWS, there literally is nothing there (I do have permissions to view the contents though...)

The API logs in CloudWatch look like this:

```
2022-07-27T03:43:06.495-05:00   Redirecting to /xyz/item?item_id=1234...
2022-07-27T03:43:06.495-05:00   [INFO] 2022-07-27T08:43:06.495Z Redirecting to /xyz/item?item_id=1234...
2022-07-27T03:43:06.496-05:00   2022-07-27 08:43:06,496 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
2022-07-27T03:43:06.496-05:00   [INFO] 2022-07-27T08:43:06.496Z ROLLBACK
2022-07-27T03:43:06.499-05:00   END RequestId: 6f449762-6a60189e4314
2022-07-27T03:43:06.499-05:00   REPORT RequestId: 6f449762-6a60189e4314 Duration: 85.62 ms Billed Duration: 86 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 204 MB
```

I have been wondering if my issue could be related to something I need to add to somewhere in my `serverless.yml`, perhaps in the `functions:` part. That currently looks like this for these two routes:

```
    events:
     - http:
          path: abc/item
          method: get
          cors: true
          private: true
          request:
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                item_id: true
      - http:
          path: xyz/item
          method: get
          cors: true
          private: true
          request:
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                item_id: true
```

Finally, it's probably good to note that I have added custom middleware to FastAPI to handle the two different database connections I need for connecting to `other_items` and `items` tables, though I'm not sure how relevant this is, considering this functions fine when redirecting locally. For this I implemented the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081977/multiple-database-connections-using-fastapi). This custom middleware is the reason for the redirect in the first place (we change connection URI based on route with that middleware), so I figured it's good to share this bit of info as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As noted [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3551#issuecomment-362605750) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218304/17865804), it is mpossible to redirect to a page with custom headers set. A redirection in the `HTTP` protocol doesn't support adding any headers to the target location. It is basically just a header in itself and only allows for a URL (a redirect response though could also include body content, if needed—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74292752/17865804)). When you add the `authorization` header to the `RedirectResponse`, you only send that header back to the client.

A suggested [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3551#issuecomment-623744065), you could use the [`set-cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) HTTP response header:

> The `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header is used to send a cookie from the
> server to the user agent (client), so that the user agent can send it back to
> the server later.

In FastAPI—documentation can be found [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-cookies/) and [here](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#set-cookie)—this can be done as follows:

```py
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

@app.get("/abc/item")
def get_item(request: Request):
    redirect_url = request.url_for('your_endpoints_function_name') #e.g., 'get_item'
    response = RedirectResponse(redirect_url)
    response.set_cookie(key="fakesession", value="fake-cookie-session-value", httponly=True)
    return response
```

Inside the other endpoint, where you are redirecting the user to, you can extract that `cookie` to authenticate the user. The cookie can be found in `request.cookies`—which should return, for example, `{'fakesession': 'fake-cookie-session-value-MANUAL'}`—and you retrieve it using `request.cookies.get('fakesession')`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73155629/17865804).

On a different note, `request.url_for()` function accepts only `path` parameters, not `query` parameters (such as `item_id` in your `/abc/item` and `/xyz/item` endpoints). Thus, you can either create the URL in the way you already do, or use the `CustomURLProcessor` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068465/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804), which allows you to pass both `path` and `query` parameters.

If the redirection takes place from one domain to another (e.g., from `abc.com` to `xyz.com`), please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804).

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I have two questions. 1] Is there anything in particular I should have as my cookie "key" and "value"? 2] When doing `request.headers['cookie']` in my `xyz/item` route, what do I do with those cookies, you mention to authenticate the user, but I'm not sure how to do that within the app itself (that's taken care of by serverless right now)

Comment: It's still not very clear to me how I should accomplish my task with your suggestion. I have tried: `response.set_cookie(key="x-api-key", value="XXX")`, I have looping over all of `requests.headers.items()` and setting `response.set_cookies()` for each key, value pair in there. And, I've tried adding `path=redirct_url` to `set_cookie()` along side it. I'm still getting the same error, and I'm not sure if that's because I'm setting the cookies wrong, or because I'm not authenticating correctly in `xyz/item` (I haven't changed anything there, because I don't know what I should change...).