# FastAPI: How to redirect from a POST endpoint to a GET endpoint carrying the data submitted using the POST request?

Tags: python, http, redirect, fastapi, starlette

I have a problem: I can’t understand how I can pass additional data to the redirect

I read the answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076517/how-to-send-redirectresponse-from-a-post-to-a-get-route-in-fastapi/73088816#73088816), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690454/how-to-redirect-the-user-back-to-the-home-page-using-fastapi-after-submitting-a/70693108#70693108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773879/fastapi-starlette-redirectresponse-redirect-to-post-instead-get-method/70777217#70777217)
but these links did not give me clarity

```js
in HTML file script:

function cmb_pos() {
        var data = {
            'dep_id': dep_id, 'div_id': div_id,
        }
        fetch('/job-history/add-new/intermediate/{{persona_id}}', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
    };
```

**first:** (*a function that accepts a POST, performs actions and redirects to another function*)

```py
from starlette.datastructures import URL

@router.post(path="/add-new/intermediate/{persona_id}",
    response_class=responses.RedirectResponse,
)
async def my_test(request: Request, item: Item, persona_id: int, service: Related):
    staff_schedule = await service.get_item_by_where(....)
    context_ext = {}
    context_ext["request"] = request
    context_ext["staff_schedule"] = staff_schedule
    context_ext["flag"] = True

    redirect_url = URL(request.url_for("create_job_history_init", persona_id=persona_id))
                  .include_query_params(context_ext=context_ext)
    return responses.RedirectResponse(
        url=redirect_url,
        status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER,
    )
```

**second**: (*function to which the redirect occurs*)

```py
@router.get(path="/persona_id={persona_id}/add-new",
    response_class=responses.HTMLResponse,
)
async def create_job_history_init(request: Request, persona_id: int,
    schedule_service: CommonsDep, context_ext: Optional[dict] = None,
):
    context = {}
    schedule = await schedule_service.get_all_item()
    related = ......
    context = schedule | related
    context["request"] = request
    context["persona_id"] = persona_id
    context["context_ext"] = context_ext

    return backend.webapps.templates.TemplateResponse(
        name="job_history/create_job_history.html",
        context=context,
    )
```

**I got this error:**

> File "/Users/pas/------/backend/webapps/job_history.py", line 276, in my_test
> ).**include_query_params(context_ext=context_ext)**
>
> File "/Users/pas/-------/.my_pers/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py", line 143, in include_query_params
> params = MultiDict(parse_qsl(**self.query**, keep_blank_values=True))
>
> File "/Users/pas/---------/.my_pers/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py", line 83, in query
> return **self.components**.query
>
> File "/Users/pas/---------/.my_pers/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py", line 66, in components
> self._components = **urlsplit(self._url)**
>
> **TypeError: unhashable type: 'URL'**

what am I doing wrong?
Is it possible to transfer additional data via a redirect?

thank you very much in advance

**update:**
in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656412/how-to-redirect-to-dynamic-url-inside-a-fastapi-endpoint/70658754#70658754) This solution is proposed, but I get an error in it

> return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
>
> AttributeError: 'URL' object has no attribute 'decode'

*parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(redirect_url))*

for me the right solution is this:

parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(redirect_url **._url** ))
after adding **._url** I was able to parse

Comment: I think I've shown everything
JSON comes from the browser to the POST method
Then this method redirects to a function with my additional data

My question is is it possible to add my data, it is in dictionary format

Comment: @Chris I'm wondering if it's possible to transmit complex data through a redirect?
or maybe you can advise how to do it correctly?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74292752/17865804). You might benefit from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804) as well.

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much for your answer
Can you tell me your idea a little more?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) , regarding the risks of passing sensitive data in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

### Current Approach

You are using JavaScript Fetch API to make a `POST` request with JSON data to the `ceate_job_history_intermediate()` endpoint of your API. Next, that endpoint responds with a `RedirectResponse` to a `GET` endpoint, after converting the JSON (body) data into query parameters and adding them to the URL (**Note:** when redirecting from a `POST` endpoint to a `GET` endpoint, the response status code has to change to `303` or `302` or `301`. Please take a look at the following posts for more details and examples: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047991/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608593/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414202/17865804)). However, as you are using a JavaScript `fetch()` request, the browser can't redirect you to the new webpage, unless you follow one of the approaches described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804).

### Issues with Current Approach

In HTTP, a [redirect response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) with status codes that fall under the `3xx` category, as mentioned above, indicate that a requested resource has been moved to a new location, and the browser should redirect the request to the new location. Hence, when returning a `RedirectResponse` from the `ceate_job_history_intermediate()` endpoint (which, as you may soon realise, is not needed at all), this response actually goes back to the browser first, which is instructed to issue a `GET` request with the data (that you submitted earlier) now being part of the query string. As you may understand, this approach makes little sense. You might as well send the data as query parameters in the first place, or, preferably, as `Form` data in the request body, as passing sensitive data in the query string poses serious security/privacy risks—have a look at the top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details on that subject. The following solutions implement the aforementioned approaches, using an HTML `<form>` instead of JavaScript Fetch API. However, in the case of passing the data as part of the query string, you might as well use a `fetch()` request instead (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804) and the following links). Please have a look at these answers from which the below approaches are derived: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804) (you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74292752/17865804) useful as well).

### Solution 1 - Passing `Form` data in the request body

**app.py** (defining `Form` parameters directly in the endpoint)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates


app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')

    
@app.post('/submit')
def get_result(request: Request, msg: str = Form(...)):
    context = {'request': request, 'msg': msg}
    return templates.TemplateResponse('result.html', context)


@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})
```

In case you had multiple `Form` parameters and wanted to define them in a class instead of the endpoint, you could use a `@dataclass`, as shown below (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650857/17865804) for more details):

**app.py** (defining `Form` parameters using  a `@dataclass`)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form, Depends
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from dataclasses import dataclass

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')
 

@dataclass
class Item:
    msg: str = Form(...)
    
    
@app.post('/submit')
def get_result(request: Request, item: Item = Depends()):
    context = {'request': request, 'msg': item.msg}
    return templates.TemplateResponse('result.html', context)

    
@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>First Page</h1>
      <form method="post" action="/submit"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         Message : <input type="text" name="msg" value="foo"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

templates/**result.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Second Page</h1>
      <p> Your message was: {{ msg }} </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Solution 2 - Passing data as part of the query string

Again, please note the risks that may come with this approach (when using query parameters), as mentioned above and discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804).

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')
 

class Item(BaseModel):
    msg: str


@app.post('/submit')
def get_result(request: Request, item: Item = Depends()):
    context = {'request': request, 'msg': item.msg}
    return templates.TemplateResponse('result.html', context)

   
@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>First Page</h1>
      <form method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit="transformFormData();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         Message : <input type="text" name="msg" value="foo"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
      <script>
         function transformFormData(){
            var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
            var qs = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(myForm)).toString();
            myForm.action = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit?' + qs;
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

templates/**result.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Second Page</h1>
      <p> Your message was: {{ msg }} </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **@Chris** Thank you very much for your work and for your detailed answers! They are incredibly helpful.
In my case, passing data through a query string does not cause any danger. This is open data.
I'm wondering if it's possible to call `create_job_history_init` again and pass new data without overloading the original page?

Comment: **@Chris**
**GET**-method `create_job_history_init` is executed and the **CONTEXT** is transferred to the browser, I select two selects on the page, I transfer the select data to the server, a database query is executed on the server, a new **CONTEXT** is created and `create_job_history_init` is executed again, new data is placed in the third selector, the page was opened in the browser (without reloading)
And most importantly, is it possible to make changes to this page with the values of the new **CONTEXT**?

Answer (score 0):

after brainstorming I found this solution for myself

*the task:
There are three comboboxes on the page, I select the first and second, the values of the third depend on the values of the first two. The values for the third i are obtained from the database. After receiving the values of the first and second, I am redirected where I create a dictionary and pass it to the initial method. Then I open the page with the combobox again and fill the third combobox with the values from the database*

I hope I explained my task clearly

**1) initial method:**

```py
@router.get(path="/persona_id={persona_id}/add-new", response_class=responses.HTMLResponse,)
async def create_job_history_init(request: Request, persona_id: int,
    schedule_service: DependsSchedule, staff_service: DependsStaff,
    context_ext: Optional[str] = None,
):
    context = {}
    status_code: status
    related = await staff_service.get_all_related_items()
    context["request"] = request
    context["persona_id"] = persona_id
    if context_ext is not None:
        tmp = eval(context_ext)
        context = context | qwe
        schedule = await staff_service.get_item_by_where(
            dep_id=tmp["department_id"], div_id=tmp["division_id"]
        )
        context["staff_schedule"] = schedule
        status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
    else:
        schedule = await schedule_service.get_all_item()
        context = context | schedule | related
        status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

    return backend.webapps.templates.TemplateResponse(
        name="job_history/create_job_history.html",
        context=context,
        status_code=status_code,
    )
```

**2) in the browser we get**

*unfortunately I don't have enough rights to post pictures*

[there are 3 comboboxes in the picture](https://imgur.com/qwiq1mp)

**3) using JS I create a redirect so it’s seamless**

```js
function cmb_pos() {
        var data = {
            'department_id': dep_id, 'division_id': div_id,
        }
        fetch('/job-history/add-new/intermediate/{{persona_id}}', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
        /* { window.location.reload(); } */
    };
```

**4) method that accepts a redirect**

```py
@router.post(path="/add-new/intermediate/{persona_id}", response_class=responses.RedirectResponse,)
async def ceate_job_history_intermediate(request: Request, item: JobHistoryIntermediate, persona_id: int):
    context_ext = {}
    context_ext["flag"] = "True"
    context_ext["department_id"] = item.department_id
    context_ext["division_id"] = item.division_id

    redirect_url = request.url_for("create_job_history_init", persona_id=persona_id)
    parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(redirect_url._url))
    parsed[4] = urllib.parse.urlencode({**{"context_ext": context_ext}})
    redirect_url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed)

    return responses.RedirectResponse(
        url=redirect_url,
        status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER,
    )
```

variable **parsed** is:

```
parsed
['http', '127.0.0.1:8000', '/job-history/persona...=3/add-new', '', '', '']
special variables
function variables
0: 'http'
1: '127.0.0.1:8000'
2: '/job-history/persona_id=3/add-new'
3: ''
4: ''
5: ''
len(): 6
```

after adding the dictionary:

```
parsed
['http', '127.0.0.1:8000', '/job-history/persona...=3/add-new', '', 'context_ext=%7B%27fl...27%3A+1%7D', '']
special variables
function variables
0: 'http'
1: '127.0.0.1:8000'
2: '/job-history/persona_id=3/add-new'
3: ''
4: 'context_ext=%7B%27flag%27%3A+%27True%27%2C+%27department_id%27%3A+1%2C+%27division_id%27%3A+1%7D'
5: ''
len(): 6
```

the address will look like this:

```
INFO: 127.0.0.1:59947 - "GET /job-history/persona_id%3D3/add-new?context_ext=%7B%27flag%27%3A+%27True%27%2C+%27department_id%27%3A+1%2C+%27division_id%27%3A+1%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

5. then **create_job_history_init** is called and the data from the database is transferred to the browser

but I still have one problem
I can't reload the page with new data